# location type(solr) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, solr, lucene, solrnet

i have this field en my solr schema.xml

```
<field name="geocode"
       type="location"
       indexed="true" 
       stored="true"
       multiValued="false" />
```

i wonder, what type of object i need in my c# class?

im trying with that, but solr throws an error.

```
 [SolrField("geocode")]
 public System.Drawing.PointF GeoCode { get; set; }


SEVERE: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{X=0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.spatial.DistanceUtils.parsePointDouble(DistanceUtil
    s.java:410)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: if you put it as a string what does the content contain ?

Comment: could save as a string, but then could utilize the functionality of Solr SpatialSearch? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of October 2012, SolrNet comes with a built in [Location](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Location.cs) class for supporting GeoSpatial searching. I would recommend getting the latest version from source - [SolrNet on GitHub](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet) or from the [nightly builds](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1) and using this class.

For queries, SolrNet added `SolrQueryByDistance` for creating geofilt or bbox queries. See [SolrNet - Querying](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying) for more detials.

Comment: Hi all, finally i do it. i could not update the dll because others things depends of that version of dll, so i migrated Location class to my project.   

  [SolrField("geocode")]
  public LocationSolr GeoCode { get; set; }